# How to wp_enqueue_script with html?

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I want to wp_enqueue_script multiple javascript with html and css.

I place the html code in a page, but it's not working on my side. Only plain text is displayed.

Here's the link: http://goo.gl/hFLla5

Here's the code

```
function add_my_script(){
  wp_register_script( 'pc', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/pc.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script('pc');
  wp_register_script( 'WWW.ProductCalculator.Data', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/WWW.ProductCalculator.Data.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script('WWW.ProductCalculator.Data');
  wp_register_style('productCalculator', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/productCalculator.css');
  }   
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

Comment: the Codex says what you are doing is ok, is there an error log? - silly question but do those files exist? do you have permissions? clicking the link and the page looks ok now so perhaps you've fixed it? but a punch of `.png`s are returning `404`

Comment: Yes, it's fixed, but I have still issue. How can I place the onclick? I mean, my html has some onclick and it's not working properly. I put this onclick with html in a page editor

Comment: What onclick? Nothing in the question about this? What does the console log say? Do you have JS loaded in correct order?